# Blocked transaction wallet on my phone

Tags: block

Ok I have a wallet on my phone that I put bitcoins in on monday, They have been blocked now for a week. How do I unblock them and the wallet I am using I can get it on my mac. Its called bitwallet by sollico software. at this point I am so confused I really just want to get the bitcoins I put in the wallet and use them to put ads up and I cant cuz its still blocked. PLEASE HELP [image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHHhs.png) Thank you so much in advanced !

EDIT:

When I go to pay it won't let me send. It keeps saying "insufficient funds." Maybe I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: when i go to pay it wont let me send unless im doing it wrong which is Very possible lol

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean that they've been "blocked" ?

That screenshot shows the "block" number that the transaction was mined in, which means that it has been confirmed on the Bitcoin network and is available for you to spend.

Have you tried to use that wallet to pay for something and you're getting an error? Because as far as I can see it seems fine:)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are confusing *block* with *blocked*. The block id shown in your screenshot is the number of the block in the blockchain where your transaction is stored in. (Meaning that the network mined and confirmed that transaction)

I personally don't use bitwallet but it seems like to use it on a Mac you need to use the [web interface](https://bitwallet.cc/).

If you want to know more about how bitcoin works check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitcoin).